# What are the differences betwwen digitalWrite() and pinMode()?

Tags: arduino

I am new in Arduino. I found a code that uses digitalWrite() and pinMode(). What I know so far these functions are used both to set the digital pins as input or output. Why the code that I found uses both of them instead of using one of them? Is it any difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pinMode` is setting whether the pin is an input or output

If the pin is set to output, it will be driven either high or low depending on what you `digitalWrite` to it

If the pin is set to input, whether is is high or low (or floating inbetween) depends on what is happening externally.

If you do a `digitalWrite` to an input pin, it wont take effect until you set the `pinMode` to output